# Python modifying and appending values to bi dimensional list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a  bi dimensional list where the inner dimension always has 3 values (first 2 values are strings and the last is an integer) and the outer dimension just holds those values like so:

`my_list=[["a","b",10],["c","d",12],["e","f",64]]`

I have a function that attempts to append a new 3 value list to `my_list`. If the first and second value of that list matches the first and second value of a list currently in my_list I would like to add together their last (integer) value .

For example attempting to add `["a","b",3]` to my_list would just change my_list like so:

`my_list=[["a","b",13],["c","d",12],["e","f",64]]`

However if attempting to add `["b","a",3]` to my_list would just change my_list like so:

`my_list=[["a","b",10],["c","d",12],["e","f",64], ["b","a",3]]`

Here's my code:

```
my_list=[["a","b",10],["c","d",12],["e","f",64]]

a=["a","b",3]

for x in my_list:
   if x[:2]==a[:2]:
      x[3]=x[3]+a[3]
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test", line 9, in <module>
    x[3]=x[3]+a[3]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: we are counting from 0, so for a list x = [1,2,3] the last element is x[2]. accessing x[3] will raise an exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List indexes in python are **zero-based**, as such your three-element lists are indexed by `0`,`1`,and `2`, not `1`,`2`, and `3` as your code expects. Also, a dictionary with `("a","b")` as keys may be a better data structure.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to do, although it wont accept inputs, the functionality is fine

```
my_list=[["a","b",10],["c","d",12],["e","f",64]]

a=["a","b",3]

for x in my_list:
   if x[0] == a[0] and x[1] == a[1]:
      x[2] += a[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest dictionaries, more efficient for such task :

```
my_dict={("a","b"):10,("c","d"):12, ("e","f"):64}

def add (key,value):
    if key not in my_dict: my_dict[key]=value
    else: my_dict[key]+=value

add(("a","b"),3)
add(("b","a"),3)  

print(my_dict)      

{('a', 'b'): 13, ('b', 'a'): 3, ('e', 'f'): 64, ('c', 'd'): 12}
```