# python how to sort differents lists with a single unique value and append it to a result list

Tags: python

I have several lists with unique values

```
>>>print(ad)
5
>>>print(ae)
2
>>>print(af)
3
>>>print(ag)
4
>>>print(ah)
1
>>>print(ai)
6
>>>print(aj)
7
```

I'm trying to sort them and append them to a empty list `results`, if one of the list is bigger than the other one.

If `ad` is bigger than `ae`, then append `ad` to `results`

I wrote that

```
    for i in range(7):
        if not results:
            results.append(ad)
        else:    
            if ad > results[i]  and ad not in results:
                results.append(ad)
            elif ae > results[i]  and ae not in results:
                results.append(ae)
            elif af > results[i]  and af not in results:
                results.append(af)
            elif ag > results[i]  and ag not in results:
                results.append(ag)  
            elif ah > results[i]  and ah not in results:
                results.append(ah)
            elif ai > results[i]  and ai not in results:
                results.append(ai)
            elif aj > results[i]  and aj not in results:
                results.append(aj)
```

Issue is I have the following error as you may already guessed ...

> IndexError: list index out of range

I hear you, how can it append when the index does not exist yet...

So I came up with that trick

```
for i in range(7):
    if len(results) < i:
        results.append(i)
```

Yet... it will not do the comparison anymore, it will just append

I've been thinking about it since Friday and I feel lost.

Any ideas that can unblock me from that ourobouros are welcome

Thanks

Comment: So you want to append values in a descending order into a list? Why not [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)?

Comment: Hi @MoonCheesez I want to implement my own merge sort. Nothing else

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, it seems very vague. are those lists the length of the lists?

Comment: Hi @Clement, I cannot be more explicit. These lists have one value , for each.

Comment: I'm trying to see if a list value is bigger than the other one, than append it to results. If not, go to the next lists

Comment: "I have several lists". No you don't. You have one list, `results` and a bunch of separate integer variables. And those separate integer variables should probably be in a list. Or if you want to keep the `ad`, `ae`, etc names, you could put them in a `dict`, but there's probably not much point in doing that & it'll just add unnecessary complication to your code.

Comment: Hi @PM2Ring, there were in a list actually. I broke them into several variables. I know I'm doing unneeded complication but I'm just trying to finish one implementation I started. There are easier way but I want to finish as it is. Simply (or not). Carrying my logic as far as I can

Comment: @AndyK could you include a full sample input and output?

Comment: @MoonCheesez updating my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python modifying and appending values to bi dimensional list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444056/python-modifying-and-appending-values-to-bi-dimensional-list)

Comment: merge sort start with a single list not multiple lists as far as I know. And also simply comparing the variable with the last element of the result list as you did here will not give a globally sorted list?

Comment: Hi @Psidom my logic is not the best. I found other solutions on the net but I want to finish it that way. If there are no other ways, please let me know and I will delete my question. But I want to finish that algorithm the way I see it. Through my human logic, things are ok but in term of implementation, I can see there are things missing in Python

Comment: @Psidom but if any of you say to me `No, you cannot do that. It is utterly stupid`, then I'll just give up. Otherwise... ;)

Comment: You can get rid of your `IndexError` by changing `results[i]` to  `results[-1]`, but your algorithm won't fully sort the data. It'll give you `[5,6,7]`, and no other elements will get appended since they are all smaller than `ad` and the subsequently added items. And even if you figure out a way to fix that your algorithm still won't handle input that contains duplicated items.

Comment: TL; DR: Stop wasting your time & energy trying to fix this mess. :) If you want to understand sorting algorithms, then look at descriptions / pseudocode of the well-known sorting algorithms and try to implement them in Python. FWIW, the standard Python sorting algorithm, [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), is _very_ good. It was developed for Python, but it's used in several other languages too. And its author, Tim Peters, is an active SO member; he sometimes even answers newbie questions...

Comment: Thanks @PM2Ring so it means what I'm trying to do cannot be done the way I was seeing it. I can bear that. And Big **Thanks** for pulling me out my mental ourobouros. Aha! I'll have a look at that timsort algorithm :))

Comment: @Psidom I'm not sure to understand what you mean...

Comment: @PM2Ring The point of learning from your mess is so that you won't make another mess!

Comment: @AndyK See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, it will help you understand what Psidom is trying to say.

Comment: @MoonCheesez: "The point of learning from your mess... " Definitely! But you've also got to learn when it's time to stop. :)

Comment: @Psidom: It's not really linear in N. The outer `for i` loop gives us a factor of N, then we have N `if` statements, giving us another factor of N, and those `x not in results` tests are also linear in N (although they're running at C speed rather than Python speed), so we actually have O(N³), making it _worse_ than BubbleSort.

Comment: @PM2Ring OK. You are right. I am wrong with the time complexity. It is not linear since it has nested if checking. but since `x not in results` are part of `if` statement, shouldn't that give `O(N^2)`? Even though I don't think it makes too much sense to discuss the time complexity since the algorithm will never scale up anyway.

Comment: @Psidom `x not in results` has to do a linear scan through the `results` list, potentially scanning through the whole list if `x` is, in fact, not in the list. So `x not in results` is O(N), although it will run a lot faster than a Python `for` loop that scans through the list. Anyway, this comments section is getting _far_ too long! Stuff like this can be discussed in the [SO Python Chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Comment: @RM2Ring I see. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for clarifying. It seems like I missed a lot before making a conclusion.

Comment: @Psidom: Hey, don't worry about it. We got there in the end. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to learn about merge sort, here is how `merge` sort can be written in python which is implemented using recursive functions and what it does is split the list into two sublists, sort each one separately and than combine them together while maintaining the order:

```
def combine(left, right):
    if(len(left) == 0):
        return(right)
    elif(len(right) == 0):
        return(left)
    else:
        if(left[0] <= right[0]):
            return([left[0]] + combine(left[1:], right))
        else:
            return([right[0]] + combine(left, right[1:]))

def msort(myList):
    if(len(myList) == 0 or len(myList) == 1):
        return myList
    splitInd = len(myList)/2
    left = myList[:splitInd]
    right = myList[splitInd:]
    return(combine(msort(left), msort(right)))
```

Some test here:

```
l = [5,2,3,4,1,6,7]
msort(l)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom I knew my sort algorithm was too long. My logic although sound in human logic is not sound in term of technical implementation. I will have to see how I can balance my logic and the technical logic. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
ad=[5]
ae=[2]
af=[3]
ag=[4]
ah=[1]
ai=[6]
aj=[7]
res.extend(ad)
res.extend(ae)
res.extend(af)
res.extend(ag)
res.extend(ah)
res.extend(ai)
res.extend(aj)
res.sort()
```

Comment: I don't think this is a valid answer. The OP stated in the question that they were implementing their own sorting algorithm.

Comment: Hi @khelili-hamza, as ppperry said, I'm implementing my own sorting algorithm

Comment: Add before else: `k=len(results)` and change `i` by `k`

Comment: That is an interesting one @KHELILIHamza